# Fill the same value for each group in R

Tags: r

I have data frame

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
x <- c("1st","","1st","1st","","","")
y <- c("2nd","2nd","","","","2nd","2nd")
z <- c("","","3rd","3rd","","","3rd")
df <- data.frame(ID,x,y,z)
df
  ID   x   y   z
1  1 1st 2nd    
2  1     2nd    
3  2 1st     3rd
4  2 1st     3rd
5  2            
6  3     2nd    
7  3     2nd 3rd
```

I want to fill the same value by ID, the output

```
  ID   x   y   z  x1  y1  z1
1  1 1st 2nd     1st 2nd    
2  1     2nd     1st 2nd    
3  2 1st     3rd 1st     3rd
4  2 1st     3rd 1st     3rd
5  2             1st     3rd
6  3     2nd         2nd 3rd
7  3     2nd 3rd     2nd 3rd
```

If the ID 1 have 1st, new variable x1 will have all of "1st" for ID1, and so on
Update data if I have more variables, but I need to use only x,y,z

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
x <- c("1st","","1st","1st","","","")
y <- c("2nd","2nd","","","","2nd","2nd")
z <- c("","","3rd","3rd","","","3rd")
m <- c(10:16)
n <- c(20:26)
df <- data.frame(ID,x,y,z,m,n)
```

Comment: With data.table, you can do `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, setdiff(names(df), "ID") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[ x != "" ][1L]), by=ID]` This also fills the blanks with `NA`, which seems like the "right" thing there.

Comment: @Frank how we keep original x,y,z, because the output x,y,z are the same x1,y1,z1

Comment: In place of `setdiff(names(df), "ID")`, write `paste0(setdiff(names(df), "ID"), ".new")` or similar. The left-hand side of `:=` is where the new var names go.

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_each(funs((.[.!=""][1])), x:z) %>% setNames(., c("ID", paste0(nm1, 1), setdiff(names(.), c("ID", nm1)))) %>% select(-ID, -m, -n) %>% bind_cols(df, .)` for the new data

Comment: I use like this, it works setDT(df)[,c("x1","y1","y2") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[ x != "" ][1L]),.SDcols=c("x","y","z"), by=ID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate_each(funs((.[.!=""][1]))) %>%
     setNames(., c("ID", paste0(names(df)[-1], 1))) %>%
     select(-ID) %>% 
     bind_cols(df, .)
#ID   x   y   z ID   x1   y1   z1
#1  1 1st 2nd      1  1st  2nd <NA>
#2  1     2nd      1  1st  2nd <NA>
#3  2 1st     3rd  2  1st <NA>  3rd
#4  2 1st     3rd  2  1st <NA>  3rd
#5  2              2  1st <NA>  3rd
#6  3     2nd      3 <NA>  2nd  3rd
#7  3     2nd 3rd  3 <NA>  2nd  3rd
```

Comment: @Stat Works for me (r 3.2.5, dplyr 0.4.3). Maybe try running the code in a new R session. Could be some conflicts among packages with similarly-named functions (?)

Comment: I am using dplyr_0.5.0

Comment: Alternately, `f = . %>% .[.!=""] %>% unique; df_clean = df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(f))` and somehow join that back.

Comment: @ Frank What if I have so many variables in dataframe, I can't apply for df, I need just 3 variables, how I apply lapply for this case

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more direct approach using `data.table`:

```
df = data.frame(ID, x, y, z, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("x1", "y1", "z1") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[which.max(x != "")]), by = ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach leveraging `tidyr::fill`. If you were using `NA` instead of empty strings (a good idea), this approach would be pretty simple:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

       # add versions of x to z with NA instead of empty strings
df %>% mutate_at(vars(x:z), funs('1' = na_if(., ''))) %>% 
    # set grouping for following operations
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    # for added columns, fill values downwards and upwards within each group
    fill(x_1:z_1) %>% fill(x_1:z_1, .direction = 'up') %>%
    # reinsert empty strings for NAs
    mutate_at(vars(x_1:z_1), funs(coalesce(., factor(''))))

## Source: local data frame [7 x 9]
## Groups: ID [3]
## 
##      ID      x      y      z     m     n    x_1    y_1    z_1
##   <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int> <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
## 1     1    1st    2nd           10    20    1st    2nd       
## 2     1           2nd           11    21    1st    2nd       
## 3     2    1st           3rd    12    22    1st           3rd
## 4     2    1st           3rd    13    23    1st           3rd
## 5     2                         14    24    1st           3rd
## 6     3           2nd           15    25           2nd    3rd
## 7     3           2nd    3rd    16    26           2nd    3rd
```